# How can I redirect users to different pages based on session data in react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

```
Argument passed in must be a string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters or an integer
    at new BSONTypeError (M:\projects-2\assigment-10-server-side\node_modules\bson\lib\error.js:41:28)
    at new ObjectId (M:\projects-2\assigment-10-server-side\node_modules\bson\lib\objectid.js:66:23)
    at ObjectId (M:\projects-2\assigment-10-server-side\node_modules\bson\lib\objectid.js:26:20)
    at M:\projects-2\assigment-10-server-side\index.js:37:34
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (M:\projects-2\assigment-10-server-side\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (M:\projects-2\assigment-10-server-side\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
    at Route.dispatch (M:\projects-2\assigment-10-server-side\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:114:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (M:\projects-2\assigment-10-server-side\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at M:\projects-2\assigment-10-server-side\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:286:22
    at param (M:\projects-2\assigment-10-server-side\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:367:14)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: You are not likely to get a good response with this question. Create the simplest, shortest code example that reproduces the problem. Take a look at [How to write effective questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex).